# Google Chrome Addon: "Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null"

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm just trying to make a Chrome extension. It opens a popup when clicked and when I click a button the textContent (also tried with innerHTML) should change. But chrome simply gives me the error.

popup.html:

```
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button id="button">Button</button>
    <p id="pa">Change me</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

popup.js:

```
document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click", hello());
function hello() {
  var text = document.getElementById("pa");
  text.textContent = "I'm a paragraph!";
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: consider changing `addEventListener("click", hello());` to `addEventListener("click", hello);`?

Comment: Same error popping up

Comment: Also move `<script src="popup.js"></script>` to the line before `</body>`?

Comment: Thanks man, it works now. But why do I need to move it there?

Comment: Because the html element doesn’t exist when the JavaScript tries to access it.

Comment: Ok, how can I mark your answer as the solving answer? ;)

Comment: I think this question has been asked before, so I'm looking for that

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/405110/how-to-accept-another-question-as-duplicate-of-ones-own-question might help